# Checking for duplicate key during signup process (Django, JS, Ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I have a javascript function that is called onsubmit:

```
function formCheck(){
    return usernameCheck() && passwordCheck();
}
```

`passwordCheck()` works fine and returns things as it should, but for some reason `usernameCheck()` is having issues:

```
function usernameCheck(){ //returns true if username is free
var ajaxHeaders = {}; //create header object
ajaxHeaders["X-CSRFToken"] = getCookie('csrftoken'); //add csrftoken from cookies for authentication server-side
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:"http://omnicloud.me/signup", 
  data:{username: $("#username").value}, 
  success:function(response){
    if(response=="true"){
       $('#passAlert').innerHTML("Sorry, that username is already taken") 
       //passalert is where all of the errors (username taken, invalid password) show up
    }
    },
headers: ajaxHeaders //settings for ajax request
});

return !($('#passAlert').value == "Sorry, that username is already taken")
}
```

On the backend:

```
def signup(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    return render_to_response('signup.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
elif request.is_ajax(): 
#query db for user with username provided via ajax, return if it exists
    try:    
        user = User.objects.get(username=request.POST.get("username")) 
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse("false",context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return HttpResponse("true", context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The A in Ajax stands for asynchronous.  The success function you have supplied is not executed immediately, it is called after the browser gets a response from the server, which will be *after* you've returned from the `usernameCheck()` function.

You can't do this check with return values, you've got to use callbacks.

Comment: That make a lot of sense. So is there Sjax, or could you elaborate a bit more on what a callback would look like? Is this a server or client side issue?

Comment: It's a client side issue.  Yes, you can make synchronous calls, but they are horrible for the end user because the browser freezes up until it gets a response form the server.

Comment: Your code is asynchronous.  It doesn't run in sequence, line-by-line.  It executes some of it, saves the success handler until later, keeps going, then at some later point calls the success handler.  Your code is written assuming that it's executed in sequence, line-by-line.  This is the problem.  You need to restructure your code to take into account it's not executed in this way.

Comment: These comments aren't the right place for an Ajax tutorial.  I strongly suggest you read one.  If you are in doubt as to what gets executed when, liberally sprinkle logging statements throughout your code.

Comment: Okay I understand more now, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!